# Changing page_cache_directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, development-environment, thin

I'm using rails 4 with **thin server** (development) with custom page_cache directory.

Rails has a default directory for saving pages cached which is "public" folder:

```
"#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/"
```

Works fine, Rails writes the page for the first time and loads cached page nicely.

But, if I change the default directory in my **application.rb** to:

```
config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/cache"
```

Rails writes the page to every request.

First access:

```
Started GET "/contato" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-05 10:21:51 -0300
Processing by PagesController#contact as HTML
Write page /Jobs/workspace/ror/hall9000/public/cache/contato.html (0.2ms)
```

Second access:

```
Started GET "/contato" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-05 10:22:34 -0300
Processing by PagesController#contact as HTML
Write page /Jobs/workspace/ror/hall9000/public/cache/contato.html (0.7ms)
```

**How to force rails to load cached pages into a different directory from default folder?**

Comment: it should not even cache in development. did you change that setting as well?

Comment: Yes, as I said: with default directory the cache works. I'm using in development for watching logs.

Comment: you actually did not say much. that's why i'm asking. your question is lacking any kind of information to help diagnosing your issue.

Comment: @phoet I've changed description. Am I clear now? Sorry about my english.